# Creating a plug in in Banno People Dashboard configuration

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I created an external application under Banno People that I want to add a Dashboard card for. When creating a plug in there, when choosing External Application, the only preconfigured external application is Autobooks, are we not able to create a plug in that's not using Autobooks?

I was expecting to see the external application I created in that drop down.

Created an external app, when attempting to choose that when creating a plug in under Dashboard configuration it's not available.

Comment: We've updated the Plugin Framework [Configuration](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/overview/configuration/) docs to clarify that the list of External Applications for the *Card Face* will only display those with a _link type_ of `PluginCard`.

Comment: I was able to create and get the card to show in Banno online, however, the card doesn't show in Mobile. Is this expected?

Comment: No, the plugin cards should show in both Banno Online and Banno Mobile. Are you certain that you're looking at the same user in both instances? We've had folks accidentally get confused about _which_ user they were using (especially if you have users with very similar or even the same names).

Comment: Along the same lines, is it the same user in the same institution in the same environment? (Some institutions have more than one environment, which again can be very similar on the surface).

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to create a plugin that is *not* the Autobooks plugin (and its External Application).

It's important to configure an [External Application](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/externalapplications/) with a *link type* of `PluginCard` to get the External Application to show up in the list of possible options when creating a [Configuration](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/overview/configuration/) for a plugin.

The External Application for the Autobooks plugin has its *link type* set to `PluginCard`. That's why it shows up in the list of possible options when selecting an External Application when you are configuring a plugin. Any *other additional* External Applications with the *link type* of `PluginCard` will show up as an option as well.